# Place an image on right side of div while other on middle

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

### CSS

```
.producttype {

  height:16%;
  width:16%;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div style="width:100%; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #888888;padding:0.5%;">
<a href="../android">
<img src="http://empedure.com/products/media/images/icons/android_128.png" class="producttype" />
</a>
<a href="../iphone">
<img src="http://empedure.com/products/media/images/icons/iphone_128.png" class="producttype" />
</a> 
<a href="../windows">
<img src="http://empedure.com/products/media/images/icons/windows_128.png" class="producttype" />
</a>
```

Following is how it looks:

[image]

I want it to be this way:

[image]

The outer should be DIV1,

`I0` = Image 1 which is left aligned

`I1,I2,I3` = three different images which should be combined at the center of DIV1

I tried `div layer` but then the `I0` was not clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you are:
http://jsfiddle.net/8u2Bp/1/

you have to set a parent div with

```
position:relative;
text-align:center;
```

then on the image you want ot stay on the left

```
position:absolute;
left: 10px [distance you want it from the left border]
```

Comment: Di niente figurati ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could just create a simple table with 1 row and 2 or 3 columns
and then place I0 in the left cell or wherever you want and align them
as you wish :)

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><img src="I0"></td>
  <td><img ... /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

(you could set the table's width to adjust better the orientation of your img)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i will prefer `div`

Comment: so add a div inside the <td> :)